# For two ordinals, $|A|\nleq |B|$, can one conclude $|A|>|B|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For two ordinals, $|A|\nleq |B|$, can one conclude $|A|>|B|$?

Notice the $<$ here represent the cardinal order.

I was thinking use the linear order relationship of $A$ and $B$ in ordinal, but I'm not sure if it's possible without the discussion of AC.

Comment: Yes, and this does not require any form of choice.

Comment: Do you know that, for any two well-ordered sets, there is an isomorphism between one of them and an initial segment of the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question first: Fix ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Assume there does not exist an injection from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. Can one conclude that there exists an injection from $\beta$ to $\alpha$?

The answer is yes. And as the comments have pointed out the axiom of choice is not required here.

An argument can take advantage of the well-order structure of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to construct the desired injection from $\beta$ to $\alpha$.

Via recursion define $f:\beta\to\alpha:\xi\mapsto\begin{cases}
\min{(\alpha\setminus\{f(\delta):\delta<\xi\})}&\text{if }(\alpha\setminus\{f(\delta):\delta<\xi\})\ne\varnothing\\
z&\text{else}
\end{cases}$

where $z$ is some dummy set which isn't an ordinal. One can show that $f$ never takes the value $z$ because of the assumption that there does not exist an injection from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. Because $z\notin\mathrm{range}(f)$, it follows that $f$ is an order-preserving injection as desired.